# Why is this code resulting in StackOverflow error:

Tags: java, interface, stack-overflow

Class C implements 2 interfaces A and B. I just wanted to print class values to verify Multiple Interface implements, instead I got StackOverflow error.

```
 interface A {
        void test();
    }

    interface B {
        void test();
    }


    class C implements A, B {
        A a = new C();
        B b = new C();

        @Override
        public void test() {
            System.out.println(a.getClass());
            System.out.println(b.getClass());
        }
    }


    public class MultiInherit{

        public static void main(String args[]){
            C c = new C();
            c.test();
        }
    }
```

Comment: `c` creates an instance of `C`, `a` and `b` also create instances of `C`, which in turn allows `a` and `b` to create instances of `C`, which in turn allows `a` and `b` to create instances of `C`, which in turn allows `a` and `b` to create instances of `C`, which in turn allows `a` and `b` to create instances of `C`, which in turn allows `a` and `b` to create instances of `C`, which in turn allows `a` and `b` to create instances of `C`, which in turn allows `a` and `b` to create instances of `C`, which in turn allows `a` and `b` to create instances of `C`... < bang >

Comment: Your `C` class is recursively instantiating another `C` class, and so, and so on, until stack overflow happens.  @MadProgrammer You said it better than I ever could :-)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Copy and Paste  

Comment: Because C constructir is calling itself

Comment: @user2717954 : constructor is not calling it self. rather it's instance variables are creating C while initialization and hence it's called recursively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by other, It goes into a Recursive Loop.
Adding an Image for better Understanding .

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When you create an instance of `C` from main

```
C c = new C();
```

1. it has to initialize the member variables of the class `C` - here they are `A a` and `B b`.
2. To initialize them, you create an instance of `C`. Goto **1**.

Answer (score 1):

when you are initializing `C c = new C();` it is instantiating it's instance variables and which you have declared as

```
A a = new C();
B b = new C();
```

here you can see it will again go to construct C and will again n again find `a` and `b` and will instantiate as `C()`. It will cause in stackOverflow

Answer (score 0):

Its because everytime you create a 'C', you end up creating two `C`s which will then create four `C` s and so on.

You can do this instead ,

```
interface A {
              void test();
        }

        interface B {
              void test();
        }


        class C implements A, B {
              A a ;
              B b ;

              @Override
              public void test() {
                    System.out.println(a.getClass());
                    System.out.println(b.getClass());
              }

              public void createObjects(){
                    a = new C();
                    b = new C();
              }


        }
```

and then call the test method ,

```
public class MultiInherit{

    public static void main(String args[]){
        C c = new C();
        c.createObjects();
        c.test();
    }
}
```